# yii2 Enable Imagine for console cron jobs

Tags: yii2, command-line-interface, yii2-advanced-app, php-imagine

I am using a block of code

```
protected function generateBgThumbs($release,$promo) {

        $thumb  = ($promo->catalog_based)
                ?Yii::$app->params['promo_cover_thumb_upload_path'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'600x600_' . $release->cover_file
                :Yii::$app->params['release_thumbs_upload'].DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'600x600_' . $release->cover_file;
        $source = ($promo->catalog_based)
                ?Yii::$app->params['promo_cover_upload_path'] .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $release->cover_file
                :Yii::$app->params['release_cover_upload'] .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $release->cover_file;

        if (!file_exists($thumb)) {
            if ($release->cover_file != '' && file_exists($source)) {
                Image::getImagine()
                        ->open($source)
                        ->thumbnail(new Box(600, 600))
                        ->save($thumb, ['quality' => 90]);
            }else{
                $this->output.="Not Generated";
            }
        }
    }
```

to generate thumbnails for the images in my yii2 application frontend, now i have some cron jobs that i run thru Cli and when i use the same method to generate the thumbnails it gives me the following error

> Your system does not support any of these drivers: gmagick,imagick,gd2

any idea if this has to do something with my `cli/php.ini` file? or something else, and yes i am using the statements

```
use yii\imagine\Image;
use Imagine\Gd;
```

in the top of my script file, i have Ubuntu installed.

Comment: try checking the output of the **requirements.php** file that comes with the framework by running it within terminal either than browser `$ php requirements.php`. I'm not sure but  think it will tell if both `GD PHP extension ` and `ImageMagick PHP extension` are well installed and activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had php 7 installed for the cli mode after the last system updates i checked by typing in `php -v` and reverted it to `php 5.7` and everything worked fine after that